# Get a blank line after div by simply leaving an empty line in the editor

Tags: css, html

I'm styling a div object so that its content behaves like a normal text.

As first thing I set its line height as the default `line-height` of a line in a paragraph.

I got this by adding the following css code

```
.myclass div {
    margin: -1.43em 0 -0.93em 0;
}
```

In this way, by writing this in the WP editor

```
badp
<div class=myclass>badp</div>
badp
```

the vertical spacing is changed as shown in the image

[image]

---

Next I'd like that an empty line after the div in the editor will correspond to a blank line in the webpage. That is, I'd like that by writing

```
badp
<div class=myclass>badp</div>

badp
```

the vertical spacing will be changed as shown in the image

[image]

I know that this can be obtained by inserting `&nbsp;` in the empty line, but is it possibile to achieve it by simply leaving an empty line as we usually do for normal text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to create a new class, say `extra-space`, with css `margin-bottom: 0.5em` and write

`<div class="myclass extra-space">...text...</div>`

when the div need more space.

Important: the class `extra-space` has to be placed AFTER the other class in the `style.css` file, otherwise the extra space will not be added.